# jQuery Validate plugin controlling CSS on error label only

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I'm trying to control the styling of the error message that appears when using the jQuery Validate plugin. I want to apply the `label label-danger` CSS classes from Bootstrap. I'm using the `errorClass` configuration attribute according to the documentation.

```
$("#frm").validate({
    errorClass: "label label-danger"
});
```

The problem is the plugin also applies these classes to the `input` element, which then renders them invisible.

See a full demo here:  http://jsfiddle.net/9me7bmny/

Is there any way to specify the error CSS class for the message and the target element independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This default demo provides the basis for two solutions below...

**Default:  http://jsfiddle.net/ndpngtrn/**

---

**1.  CSS targeting...**

If you have not changed the default error message element, it will be a `label`.  You would use CSS to target this `label` element independently from the `input` elements.  This is probably the easiest way to discriminate the styling of the `input` from the styling of the `label`.

```
label.yourerrorclass {
    /* some styling */
}

input.yourerrorclass {
    /* some other styling */
}
```

**DEMO 1:  http://jsfiddle.net/ndpngtrn/3/**

---

**2.  Options for `.validate()`...**

Otherwise, the `highlight` and `unhighlight` options control the application of classes to each element.  You would have to write custom `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions to over-ride the default behavior.  Since `highlight` and `unhighlight` only affect the styling on the input element and not the error labels, you have an opportunity to discriminate CSS between the two.

- **error labels**: default error/valid CSS classes applied internally by the plugin.  Style can only be changed by assigning different classes via the `errorClass` and `validClass` options or by changing the CSS.
- **input elements**: CSS styles are applied/removed via the `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions.  By default, the same error/valid CSS classes as the error labels, however, you can over-ride `highlight` and `unhighlight` to apply/remove any styles you wish, thereby achieving a different style than the error labels.

To simply stop `highlight` and `unhighlight` from adding/removing any classes to each `input` element, use a `return false`.  *(see the commented out lines if you also want to add/remove other classes to your input elements independently from your error messages)*

```
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    return false;
    //$(element).addClass('foo').removeClass('bar');
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    return false;
    //$(element).addClass('bar').removeClass('foo');
}
```

The `errorClass` and `validClass` arguments represent the respective default classes defined by the plugin.

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/ndpngtrn/5/**

**Solution 2 applied to your jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/9me7bmny/2/**